# VBA - Delete all rows that do not contain at least 1 highlighted cell

Tags: excel, vba, filter, filtering

Looking for VBA code to delete all rows that do not contain at least 1 highlighted cell (interior color used: REDINDEX).

Sample data sheet with randomly highlighted cells

[image]

Comment: I tried creating a button; however, it didn't work. I created an ActiveX button. The button was a private sub and then I called the DeleteAllRowsWithNoHighlightedCells Public Sub... then I put in the Public Sub DeleteAllRowsWithNoHiglightedCells... but each time it gave me error or Sub or Function not defined... I am also unclear on the second part of the code you provided and to be honest I'm not sure where to put it... Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I'm completely new to VBA and trying to make it work. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
Public Sub DeleteAllRowsWithNoHighlitedCells()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim aktRow As Range
Dim owsh As Worksheet
Set owsh = ActiveSheet
iRow = 1
lastColumn = 7
Do Until owsh.Cells(iRow, 1) = ""
    Set aktRow = owsh.Range(Cells(iRow, 1), Cells(iRow, lastColumn))
    If Not AktRowHasHighlightedCells(aktRow) Then
        owsh.Rows(aktRow.Row).Delete
        iRow = iRow - 1
    End If
    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
```

End Sub

Private Function AktRowHasHighlightedCells(ByVal aktRow As Range) As Boolean
     Dim aktcell As Variant

```
 For Each aktcell In aktRow.Cells

    If aktcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        AktRowHasHighlightedCells = True
        Exit Function
    End If

Next aktcell
AktRowHasHighlightedCells = False
```

End Function

To explain what i mean. First you have to create a Button and put the **DeleteAllRowsWithNoHiglitedCells** - Procedure behind the Click-Event. Then until Column1 for each row  is not empty, every Cell in the selected Row from column1 to lastColumn (you have to define or you also can get the lastusedColumn via VBA) is checked for a Interior.Colorindex = 3 (hard coded red) If the Function **AktRowHasHighlightedCells** is false, the row will be deleted and the rowCounter will be decreased.